# How to cut the values till particular character?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having an array $IPAddress which contains IPv4 and IPv6 address like below.

> IPAddress : {166.33.77.15, fe90::68fe:7602:d981:2cb}
>
> IPAddress : {166.33.77.18, fe87::67c0:8476:3509:fb7a}
>
> IPAddress : {166.33.77.65, fe80::c08e:f5ec:5095:e7ec}

I would like to store in my IPaddress array only the IPv4 address. I need to cut after '{' till ','. How to do this using powershell?

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: @stej: Some substring method in .net might be used. I have not used that in powershell

Comment: This looks like the output of `Format-List` of objects that have a property `IPAddress` which is an array of addresses. In that case you'd be *nuts* to throw string manipulation or regex at it. You have *PowerShell*, after all ;-)

Comment: @Joey: Yes, It was some kind of object it seems. VMware PowerCLI returned that IP addresses. I was applying these string functions and became nuts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result is an object then you can simply do:

```
$IPAddress[0]
```

If it's a string, try using a regex:

```
'IPAddress : {166.33.77.15, fe90::68fe:7602:d981:2cb}' -replace '^IPAddress : {([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking objects ;)

Comment: Finally i found it was some kind of object . I was not able to apply string function on them. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way but I think (not... I'm sure!) there's something better using regex!

```
$IPAddress = $IPAddress | % { $_.Substring( $_.IndexOf('{')+1 , $_.IndexOf(',') - ($_.IndexOf('{')+1))
```

Edit: simple way with regex (not verifying if IP address is a valid ipaddress)

```
$IPAddress = $IPAddress |  select-string "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" | select -ExpandProperty matches | select -ExpandProperty value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in PowerShell very easily for this.

```
$IPAddress = @(`
    "IPAddress : {166.33.77.15, fe90::68fe:7602:d981:2cb}", `
    "IPAddress : {166.33.77.18, fe87::67c0:8476:3509:fb7a}", `
    "IPAddress : {166.33.77.65, fe80::c08e:f5ec:5095:e7ec}")

foreach($ip in $IPAddress) { 
    if ($ip -match "{.*,") {
        Write-Host $matches[0].substring(1, $matches[0].length - 2)
    }
}
```

`$matches` is a special variable which is set after using the `-match` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I got pretty much the same answer as Shay, but I'll add that you don't need to foreach the replace.  It'll do the entire array at once:

```
$array -replace '^IPAddress : {([^,]+).+$','$1'
```